# get input data in controller yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

i am trying get input field from a form in yii2. i need to use it in a controller depending on the value. i am trying to see the value using var_dump but it is not working. i am getting "NULL" as the value.. Or is there a way to make a form use different controllers.

controller

```
 public function actionBlog()
 { 
     $thumbs= new Thumbs; 
     $thumbs->user=Yii::$app->user->identity->email;
     $thumbs->topic_id=Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('id');
     $ra=Yii::$app->request->post('rate');
     var_dump($ra);
     if(ra=='down'){
         if ($thumbs->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $thumbs->validate()) {
             $thumbs->load($_POST);
             $thumbs->save();
             return $this->refresh();
         }
     } else {
         return $this->refresh();
     }
     return $this->render('blog',[
         'thumbs' => $thumbs,
     ]);
 }
```

this is my view

```
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => "contact-form"
        ]); 
  ?>
  <?= $form->field($thumbs, 'rate')?>
  <?= Html::submitButton('Update', ['blog'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

i also tired using doing it like this

```
$rr=Yii::$app->request->post($thumbs)['rate'];
var_dump( $rr);
```

and i get this error:

> Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Comment: check output of `var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post());`

Comment: Try to format your codes before posting. Also, avoiding PHP short tags is always a good practice, as some versions of PHP disabled short tags by default.

Comment: @Raptor since Yii 2 requires PHP 5.4 or newer it's save to use short tags because these are available for sure.

Comment: @arinze there are so many issues in this short code... anyway, your form class is called Thumbs so there should be $_POST['Thumbs']['rate'] available.

Comment: i just tried it  $_POST['Thumbs']['rate'] it is not working . this is the error Illegal offset type... and what are the issues with the my code.

Comment: @arinze  please update your answer and show the result for var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post())

Comment: var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post()) output is "array(0) { }":

Answer (score 0):

You have a error in if(ra=='down') condition, '$' is missing.

Comment: the vardump is returning null

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right  .. you should try

```
$ra=Yii::$app->request->post(['Thumbs']['rate']);
```

Comment: Undefined index: rate

Comment: Please update your question and shom  me the content of var_dump(ra=Yii::$app->request->post(['Thumbs']);

Comment: Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Comment: Are you sure you have somethings in  $_POST  .. try var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post); and repeat the previous without ra=  .. var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post(['Thumbs']);